# Django Rest Framework update() with kwargs from validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can I update instance in one line without specifying all instance fields?

For example:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

So imagine if there's many more fields next to name and address.
Can I do something extracting kwargs from validated_data? Just like in create() method:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Person.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a one-liner but short enough ([extracted from the drf sources](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L969-L985)):

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: But why not just...instance = super().update(instance, validated_data) ?

Comment: would work but you wouldn't have to override `update` at all in the first place and this didn't seem to be what the OP asked for.

Comment: permanent link to the DRF source: [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a1b35bb44b7c9251c8b7bc995aa6598044f1d3ef/rest_framework/serializers.py#L991-L1015)